# How can I write this better?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

This piece of code is repeated a lot throughout my code, but `x`, `y`, and `z` change of course. Is there a better way?

```
if (x == "hour") {
  y = z * 60;
} else if (x == "day") {
  y = z * 1440;
} else if (x == "week") {
  y = z * 10080;
}
```

Update..there is store.getters involved. They are not plain variables.

```
    if (this.tempUsersTriggerIntervelIdentifier === "minute") {
        this.convertedNewUsersTriggerIntervel =
          this.$store.getters.getUsersTriggerTime;
      } else if (this.tempDefaultRunIntervelIdentifier == "hour") {
        this.convertedNewDefaultRunIntervel =
          this.$store.getters.getOrganizationsDefaultTriggerTime * 60;
      } else if (this.tempDefaultRunIntervelIdentifier == "day") {
        this.convertedNewDefaultRunIntervel =
          this.$store.getters.getOrganizationsDefaultTriggerTime * 1440;
      } else if (this.tempDefaultRunIntervelIdentifier == "week") {
        this.convertedNewDefaultRunIntervel =
          this.$store.getters.getOrganizationsDefaultTriggerTime * 10080;
      }
```

I want to do the best possible practice.

Comment: Create a function, put that code there, make `x`, `y`, and `z` parameters. Re-use the function. Why isn't this an option?

Comment: To me this looks much readable, however you can use turnery operator too x == "hour" ? z * 60:x == "day"? z * 1440: x == "week"? z * 10080:0

Comment: Sorry, one variable is a store. getter. I updated the question. This makes a difference, if I am not wrong ?

Comment: if this is all around your code, there's probably a bigger structural problem. Consider using one unit of time universally. Usually this is epoch, the number of seconds since 1970/01/01 00:00:00. Convert this at the edges of your application, ie reading/writing to the database or when updating a GUI component

Comment: "*Update..there is store.getters involved. They are not plain variables.*" I do not see how that makes a difference. Can you explain why `this.convertedNewUsersTriggerIntervel = someFunction(this.tempUsersTriggerIntervelIdentifier, this.$store.getters.getOrganizationsDefaultTriggerTime)` cannot work the same way?

Answer (score 5):

```
const factors = {
 'hour' : 60,
 'day'  : 1440,
 'week' : 10080
};
let y = z * factors[x];
```

Try this 'map object' style. You could replace

> factors[x]

with

> factors.x

but it would be not TypeScript friendly if you would ever switch to ts.

**[ANSWER ON UPDATED QUESTION]**

Your code is not cool! You check cases from different object references which is not clean and gets tough to grasp. Could be much cleaner. Anyway, you could try this:

```
if (this.tempUsersTriggerIntervelIdentifier === "minute") {
    this.convertedNewUsersTriggerIntervel = this.$store.getters.getUsersTriggerTime;
} else {
    this.convertedNewDefaultRunIntervel = 
        this.$store.getters.getOrganizationsDefaultTriggerTime *
        factors[this.tempDefaultRunIntervelIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, one variable is a store. getter. I updated the question. This makes a difference, if I am not wrong ?

Comment: Also keep in mind that there is CodeReview for this kind of questions https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MEAG you can add function result and enven function in an object ... so you can do it too.

BTW I think this methode is way better since you don't have to iterate on an if forest or a switch case (that's less perfomrant in cpu exec but better in ram, choose what you want).

Also it can be completly typescript friendly !!

Comment: @MEAG I updated my answer. Pls mark as accepted if it works for you

Comment: Yea sure. Didn't apply it yet, but i'm considering it the solution. Thanks alot !

Answer (score 2):

I think the switch is the most suitable way to handle multiple conditions.

```
function getMinutes (x, z) {
    switch (x) {
        case 'hour': z *= 60; break;
        case 'day': z *= 1440; break;
        case 'week': z *= 10080; break;
        default: z *= 60; break;
    }
    return z;
}

// somewhere in your code
const y = getMinutes('day', 1);
```

Comment: Sorry, one variable is a store. getter. I updated the question. This makes a difference, if I am not wrong ?